# joomla! upgrade from 1.5.26 to 2.5 jUpdate error and more

Tags: joomla, migration, joomla2.5, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

Migration or upgrade, whatever, I want to get rid of my 1.5 site. I read some articles, watched a few tutorials however I could not beat it.

First, I upgraded my 1.5.2 to latest 1.5.26. Then I installed jUpgrade 2.5.2 extension from admin panel, activated it but after clicking to upgrade: nothing happened. The big arrow is not clickable.

Then I downloaded redMigration. There were two distinct .zip files in it. "plg_redMIGRATOR_1.0.0_j15" and "com_redMIGRATOR_1.0.0_j25_j3". Former was installed as an extension and activated (also I did password operations) but there is nothing. No way to run it. When I tried to install "com_redMIGRATOR_1.0.0_j25_j3" from extensions, it says there is no XML file to install. So I am stucked! I've been trying it hard but I have nothing.

How can I fix these problems?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Joomla management, and not programming as [defined for StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), try asking on [the Joomla Q&A StackExhange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

The not click-able issue is most likely down to the javascript not working.
When I've seen this before, it has been just that JUpgrade needs a newer version of Mootools.

Have you enabled the Mootools Upgrade Plugin?

See: [http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Migrating_from_Joomla_1.5_to_Joomla_2.5#Enable_Mootools_Upgrade_Plugin](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5%3aMigrating_from_Joomla_1.5_to_Joomla_2.5#Enable_Mootools_Upgrade_Plugin)